# Material design in mobile browser

Tags: website-design, web-app, accessibility, material-design

Can a website or web-app can be developed using material design(flat) for a mobile browsers ??
Example:chrome,Firefox etc.

Comment: This seems to be off topic. What is the UX question?

Answer (score 1):

[Material design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-goals) is a guideline that is meant to be used for any device. Although it has practices and recommendations for Mobiles it usually gives tips for desktops too, so it is independent of being for an app a web on desktop or mobile.

> Develop a single underlying system that allows for a unified experience across platforms and device sizes. Mobile precepts are fundamental, but touch, voice, mouse, and keyboard are all ﬁrst-class input methods.

You can check [design awards](https://design.google.com/articles/material-design-awards-2016/) they give every year, where there are different ways of implementing Material design.

Comment: will mobile browsers support , will there not be rendering problems or any sort of those.

Comment: we can absolutely design there are no doubts in that. i just wanted to check is there someone who has tried developing it to mobile browsers.

Comment: It is a UX and UI guide so it doesn't enter the technical aspects (mostly), which are the ones that could led to rendering problems.

Comment: @Harshith material design and rendering of a website have no relation with each other. They both are totally different. Material Design, the name itself represent "Design", is just part of UI-UX It is all about user's view not the development. It is not like that if you're using Material Design then code would ne impletemented diffrently.

Comment: any examples of websites

Comment: Material website itself. Check the link to the awards, and the ones of last year too, I think "kitchen stories" is closer to what you are looking for.